# Update MySQL Large table with another table's data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Two Tables in same database, Table 1 contains approx 4 million records and table 2 has 100K

Table 1 look like

```
id      | Balance
-----------------
234344  | 4.3
232434  | 4.3
243244  | 4.3
232443  | 4.3
100001  | 2.3
100002  | 2.3
100003  | 2.3
100004  | 2.3
100005  | 2.3
```

Table 2

```
id      | Balance
-----------------
234344  | 11.555
232434  | 12.32
243244  | 1.0
232443  | 2.6
```

I need to copy the value of Balance from Table 2 to Table 1 based on check ID in each table

Tips for this UPDATE statement ? and please note that tables are too big

need faster solution

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the id fields in both tables are indexed. This will greatly aid the next query below

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id SET table1.Balance = table2.Balance
```

Please dont forget if this helps to accept the answer :)